# Is Firebase Cloud Messaging authentication necessary?

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have server in php with custom user authentication. I'm trying to create chat with Firebase, and after reading docs I'm still confused id I need to authenticate my users for Firebase, and if so should I do it with signInWithCustomToken?

Any other tips on how should I proceed are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I wrote some quick documentation below. But to have a more complete answer, you will have to share more technical details about what your app currently does. If you're new to Firebase, I recommend taking one of our codelabs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to authenticate users for them to *receive* FCM messages.

You do need to pass the FCM Server key to **send** messages to devices however. You can see an example of that in the `Authorization` header here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Comment: Thanks for answer! To answer your question from main comment, I would like to send and receive chats between any two users between web app and android app. If I don't need to authenticate users, how would then app know which comment goes from which to which user?

Comment: It sounds like **your app** requires a way to identify users. So while it's not a requirement from FCM, your app may well need it. One way to identify users without requiring them to sign is, is by [using Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). But it sounds like you're quite new to this type of application architecture, so I highly recommend that you take the Firebase codelab before continuing: https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs (search for the "Codelabs" heading)

Comment: Did this change recently? I'm getting this error when trying to get an FCM token on web. 

`[token-subscribe-failed] [firebase_messaging/token-subscribe-failed] Messaging: A problem occurred while subscribing the user to FCM: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.`

Comment: The Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK for web clients does not have an API to subscribe to a topic. That functionality is only available by calling the REST API, which does require an OAuth token. This question was specifically about Firebase Auth and JWTs, which is quite different from the OAuth tokens needed for the REST API, which is meant to be called from a server/trusted environment.